# Why am I getting an IllegalFormatConversionException?

Tags: java, format

I'm generating some random keys which I need to be of size k (bits). I want them in binary format. As expected, the keys which have their very left bits being 0 have a size less than k. I want to format those Strings so they have their missing zeros and have a size of k bits again.

The thing is that `return String.format("%0128d", bg.toString(2));` results in `java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.lang.String`. What am I doing wrong?

```
// Method to generate random keys of k bits each
public String keyGenerator(int k) {

    SecureRandom srandom = new SecureRandom();
    // Constructor: BigInteger(int numBits, Random rnd)
    // Create a random big integer of k bits using secure random
    BigInteger bg = new BigInteger(k, srandom);

    // If the very left values are zeros they disappear. We need to pad the String to have k bits
    if (bg.toString(2).length() < k) {
        return String.format("%0128d", bg.toString(2));
    }

    // Return the bg with radix 2 (= show it in binary)
    return bg.toString(2);

}
```

Comment: `%d` is for formatting an integer. You are giving it a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

%d is to display integers. If you want to display String as your `bg.toString()`
you must use `%s` and format it properly.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html for all formatter options.

Comment: I feel stupid, although `return String.format("%0128s", bg.toString(2));` doesn't work either. I get a `java.util.FormatFlagsConversionMismatchException: Conversion = s, Flags = 0` exception.

Comment: Please check the paragraph starting with BigDecimal. %0 is not allowed for character conversion: i.e.: you cannot pad a string with 0....